# How to update multiple columns with one query?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am trying to update multiple columns of a table following an inquirer prompt. I am getting an error following the db.query statement. Here is my code:

```
function updateEmpRole() {
    db.query(
        'SELECT * FROM role',
        function(err, results) {
            const role = results.map(role => {
                return {name: role.title, value: role.id}
                });
                if (err) throw err;
    db.query(
        'SELECT * FROM employee',
        function(err, results) {
            const employee = results.map(employee => {
                return {name: employee.first_name+' '+employee.last_name, value: employee.id}
                });
                if (err) throw err;
    db.query(
        'SELECT * FROM employee WHERE manager_id IS NULL',
        function(err, results) {
            const manager = results.map(manager => {
                return {name: manager.first_name+' '+manager.last_name, value: manager.id}
                });
                if (err) throw err;
                inquirer.prompt([
                    {
                        type: 'list',
                        name: 'id',
                        message: 'Select an employee to update:',
                        choices: employee
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'list',
                        name: 'role_id',
                        message: 'Please assign a new role:',
                        choices: role
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'list',
                        name: 'manager_id',
                        message: 'Please assign a manager:',
                        choices: manager
                    }
                ])
                .then((response) => {
                    db.query(
                        `UPDATE employee SET role_id = ?, manager_id = ? WHERE id = ?`,
                        response,
                        function(err, results) {
                            console.table('Employee successfully updated.');
                            if (err) throw err;
                            startApp();
                        })
                    })
})})})};
```

How should I properly specify SET? I only want to update role_id and manager_id.

Comment: The **conventional** syntax is for a SET statement is as follows: `UPDATE table_name 
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ... 
WHERE condition;`. But note that your particular SQL server may require a slightly different syntax.